# Error : Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm totally new to Android Studio and came up to this error that says it can not download gradle-3.5.1.pom and gradle-3.5.3.jar from Google or jcenter repositories. But when I tried downloading them manually it was easy and straight forward though.

This is what I have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() 
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() 
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my errors are:

```
  ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.jar
Required by:
    project :
Open File
```

Comment: Is **Offline Work in Android studio** enabled? Check through **File>Settings>Build>Gradle->Offline work** is checked or not.

Comment: do not forget sanctions. it is restricted in your country

Comment: As https://stackoverflow.com/users/6750327/hooman told do not forget limitations for connecting to google in certain regions.You could test with a good speed vpn . Also test your internet speed. And as 3rd solution please upgrade your gradle version and in all of these ways you must uncheck offline mode in setting .

Comment: it is not offline and i always use vpn so i dont think that it would be restricted how can i completely delete all my android studio settings? i uninstalled it but the settings were the same when i installed it again

Comment: Pay attention to sanctions as @Hooman said And in addition Update your IDE Version! It may work
Also, have a look at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38934#issuecomment-523298507

Answer (score 1):

go to **build.gradle** (project version) and just update it from:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me! check by right clicking or keeping your cursor on the
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build :gradle :3.5.3'`and you will get suggestion by the studio for the latest version. change it accordingly.
`dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3' }`